# Flexbox nested columns

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to nest some flexbox columns inside a flexbox.
I have this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex height">
    <div class="col-md-6 red">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 orange">

      <div class="flex flex-columns">
        <div class="row black flex">
          <div class="col-md-3 yellow">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9 green">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row white flex">
          <div class="col-md-6 blue">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 indigo">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS is like this:

```
.container {
  border: 1 px solid pink;
}

.height {
  min-height: 500px;
}

.flex {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-columns {  
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  flex: 1;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.indigo {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.violet {
  background-color: violet;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.white {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Here is a diagram illustrating what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

and here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/PqWqKx?editors=110

Hopefully you can understand what I am trying to do, but I can't get it to work properly.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `.green{background:blue} .blue{background:orange}`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it well, you want

```css
.flex-columns {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.row {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```css
@import '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css';
.flex {
  min-height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-columns {  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.row {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0; /* Remove stupid bootstrap margins */
}
.red    { background-color: red;    }
.orange { background-color: orange; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.green  { background-color: blue;   }
.blue   { background-color: orange; }
.indigo { background-color: indigo; }
.violet { background-color: violet; }
.black  { background-color: black;  }
.white  { background-color: white;  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 red">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 orange">
      <div class="flex flex-columns">
        <div class="row black"></div>
        <div class="row violet"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not quite, the flex-columns I want to behave like rows, i.e the .black and .voilet should be sat on top of each other 100% width and equal heights.

Comment: @r3plica You said: "*I am trying to get the 'rows' insde the flex-columns to appear as columns*". And now you say they should behave like rows?

Comment: yeah, looks like I was getting confused with what I wanted! sorry about that. I have updated my question

Comment: @r3plica But then I think your original code behaved like you want now. I don't understand, your codepen seems to have changed. Well, try `.flex-columns {flex-direction: column}`.

Comment: what does the .row { flex: 1; } do? that seems to make my row's do what I expect.

Comment: @r3plica It sets the default main size to 0, and a flex grow factor of 1. So the `.row` will fill the flex container equally. See [Common Values of `flex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

Comment: ok, I have updated my question and my codepen to match my issue. I hope you can see what the issue is now.

Comment: @r3plica Now you need `.flex-columns { height: 100%;}`

Answer (score 1):

I modified your HTML and CSS to make the results fit the image (colors notwithstanding).

1. Added a `padding` to every div
2. Added `flex-grow` to some of the flex-items, to make them fill their parents (by adding the `row` class to them)
3. Removed `div.flex.flex-columns` and change its `class`es to its parent, so it changes to `div.col-md-6.orange.flex.flex-columns`. It's superflous and messing your layout.
4. Modify the `flex-grows` of the purple `div`s (in the image) to change their ratios

You can run the following snippet to see the results.
The inner `div`s still need some padding to really mimic the image, but I'm guessing that's not the main point of your question.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
div {
  padding: 10px;
}
.height {
  min-height: 500px;
}
.flex {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  flex: 1;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 3;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 3;
}
.indigo {
  background-color: indigo;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
.violet {
  background-color: violet;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
.white {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex height">
    <div class="col-md-6 red row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 orange row flex flex-columns">
      <div class="row black flex">
        <div class="col-md-3 yellow row"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9 green row"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row white flex">
        <div class="col-md-6 blue row"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 indigo row"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `.flex-column` shouldn't have a `flex-direction` set:

```
.flex-columns {  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  align-content: stretch;
}
```

add the following to your css:

```
.flex-columns > .row{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  margin: 0; /* this is to reset the column padding/margins added by bootstrap */
}
```

forked pen - http://codepen.io/braican/pen/PqWqvr

```css
@import '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css';
.flex {
  min-height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-columns {  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  align-content: stretch;
}
.flex-columns > .row{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  margin: 0;
}


.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: blue;
}

.blue {
  background-color: orange;
}

.indigo {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.violet {
  background-color: violet;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 red">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 orange">

      <div class="flex flex-columns">
        <div class="row black">
        </div>

        <div class="row white">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```